# Passing method name as function argument

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm probably missing something obvious here, what I'm trying to do is extract part of this Django view into a function since I'm using same code multiple times:

```
def method_name(pk, method_name, model_name):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Document, id=pk)
    wb = instance.method_name()
    with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
        wb.save(tmp.name)
        tmp.seek(0)
        stream = tmp.read()
    instance.model_name.save('POPDV.xlsx', ContentFile(stream), save=False)
    instance.save()
```

I would like to pass model_name as a method name (in bold). What is the correct way to do this?
My solution would be calling `instance.__getattribute__ ("model_name").save(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to access attributes by name:

```
wb = getattr(instance, method_name)()
# ...
getattr(instance, model_name).save(...)
```

`getattr(obj, name)` implicitly goes through the various attribute lookup options:
`obj.__getattribute__(name)`, `obj.__dict__['name']`, `obj.__getattr__(name)`

Usually, you do not call magic methods directly. They often are hooks for built-in methods or operators, e.g. `iter(obj)` calls `obj.__iter__()`, `len(obj)` calls `obj.__len__()`.